How do we use WebView in jetpack compose?
I'm aiming to integrate a WebView into my Jetpack Compose project, allowing users to interact with specified URLs. Initially, I experimented with the default Android WebView, but its functionality was limited for my needs. I require full control over user interactions, including typing, link navigation, form submission, error handling, and more.
After some exploration, I stumbled upon io.github.KevinnZou:compose-webview:0.33.4, which seemed promising as it provided the necessary functionalities. However, to my disappointment, it's deprecated and no longer maintained.
Could someone kindly suggest a robust alternative method or library for seamlessly implementing a WebView within a Jetpack Compose project? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
